# How to install pyaudio in windows 10 error ('list' object has no attribute 'read')

Tags: python

i have try to install pyaudio using `pip install pyaudio` but i got some error

i am also try many command but i not got any sollution please tell me the solution of this error

```
Collecting PyAudio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: PyAudio
  Running setup.py install for PyAudio ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\hemant\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-54xerlo0\\PyAudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-4fium3ew\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-54xerlo0\PyAudio\setup.py", line 122, in <module>
        extra_link_args=extra_link_args)
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 78, in run
        _build_ext.run(self)
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
        self._build_extensions_serial()
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 473, in _build_extensions_serial
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 199, in build_extension
        _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 533, in build_extension
        depends=ext.depends)
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 345, in compile
        self.initialize()
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 238, in initialize
        vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 178, in msvc14_get_vc_env
        return get_unpatched(msvc14_get_vc_env)(plat_spec)
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 132, in _get_vc_env
        vcvarsall, vcruntime = _find_vcvarsall(plat_spec)
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 92, in _find_vcvarsall
        _, best_dir = _find_vc2017()
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 81, in _find_vc2017
        ], encoding="mbcs", errors="strict").strip()
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
        **kwargs).stdout
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\run\__init__.py", line 145, in __new__
        process = cls.create_process(command, stdin, cwd=cwd, env=env, shell=shell)
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\run\__init__.py", line 121, in create_process
        shlex.split(command),
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\shlex.py", line 305, in split
        return list(lex)
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\shlex.py", line 295, in __next__
        token = self.get_token()
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\shlex.py", line 105, in get_token
        raw = self.read_token()
      File "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\shlex.py", line 136, in read_token
        nextchar = self.instream.read(1)
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\hemant\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-54xerlo0\\PyAudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-4fium3ew\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\hemant\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-54xerlo0\PyAudio\
```

i am also use this command but i got same error

```
python -m pip install PyAudio

pip install pyaudio --user

pip install --allow-unverified=pyaudio pyaudio
```

tell me the solution of this error thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Supported Python versions are Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6
Maybe you are using other Python version?